# Compare two arrays with wild cards in UNIX

Tags: bash, loops, unix, wildcard, filenames

I'm trying to compare two arrays in a loop one array with file names and other array with file path including filename. I'm not able to use wild cards in my code. Please give your views and suggestions if I can work in any other way.

```
.~/.env
defaultlist = ("file1" "file2" "file3") #contains only filename
checklist=/filepath=("${filename}"/*.csv) # second array which is extracts all csv files in the path

for i in "${defaultlist[@]}". #iterating default list
 do
  if [["$i" =~ "$checklist[@]}"]]
  then echo "$i   File present"
  else echo "$i   not present"
  fi
 done
```

For better understanding, the above code will only match complete identical names in both lists but in my case one list has just filenames and the other list has filepath/filename appended with random numbers. So can we use the wild card while comparing two arrays? If not is there any other way to achieve my target?

Both arrays will not be of the same length.

Comment: *I'm not able to use wild cards in my code.* Why not?

Comment: (This would be pretty trivial in `zsh` with wildcards, btw)

Comment: @nick: What is the `[["$i" in "$checklist[@]}"]]` supposed to do? Are you inventing a new syntax here?

Comment: @nick : To test whether a certain array contains a certain value in bash, you have to loop through the array and test the individual elements until you find a matching one.

Comment: @nick : I'm voting to close the question becaues it is not clear to me whether your problem is in matching the filename or in searching the list. Please clarify this in your question.

Comment: @user1934428, Edited my question. I'm trying the same as you mentioned to loop through the default list with the acquired list from the path. It doesn't work as both arrays are not completely identical. The default array will have bar but the array acquired from path will have path/bar_2029.csv.

Comment: @nick : Of course the content is not identical - if it were, you wouldn't need two arrays. The crucial point is that they have the same size, where the elements correspond one-to-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For better understanding, the above code will only match complete identical names in both lists…

Not really, because the code above is malformed.

One can always do something ugly and “quadratically” (meaning `${#defaultlist[@]} × ${#checklist[@]}`) complex to cross-match the lists:

```sh
defaultlist=('file1' 'file2' 'file3')
checklist=("${defaultlist[@]/%/".$((RANDOM)).suffix"}")
checklist=("${checklist[@]/#/'/some/path/to/'}")
defaultlist+=('file4' 'file5')  # Not in checklist.

printf 'defaultlist: [%s]\nchecklist: [%s]\n\n' \
       "${defaultlist[*]}" "${checklist[*]}"

for name_fragment in "${defaultlist[@]}"; do
  for full_path in "${checklist[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${full_path##*/}" == *"$name_fragment"* ]]; then
      echo "${name_fragment} present"
      continue 2
    fi
  done
  echo "${name_fragment} NOT present"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use Bash arrays, but the [`comm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) utility:

```sh
$ ls
bar.csv baz.csv foo.csv
$
$ comm -12 <(printf '%s\n' {foo,bar}.csv | sort) <(printf '%s\n' *.csv)
bar.csv
foo.csv
```

- `comm` by defaults prints three columns: lines found just in the first file, lines found just in the second file and lines common to both. The `-12` flag, which is short for `-1 -2`, will remove the first two columns, thus printing out just the third one which contains lines common to both files
- `<(...)` creates a temporary file with the output of the enclosed command (see [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html))
- I've used `printf` so that I can easily print a list of arguments, each on its own line (`\n`)
- `comm` requires sorted lines, which is why there's a `sort` in there

If you need to compare them under a directory, you could just prepend that directory's name, like this:

```
$ ls temp
bar.csv baz.csv foo.csv
$
$ comm -12 <(printf '%s\n' temp/{foo,bar}.csv | sort) <(printf '%s\n' temp/*.csv)
temp/bar.csv
temp/foo.csv
```

---

A solution for non-exact matching might look like this:

###### check.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -so errexit
shopt -so nounset
shopt -s nullglob

declare -a prefixes=(foo bar missing)

for prefix in "${prefixes[@]}"; do
  echo "FILES WITH PREFIX: $prefix"

  # Build a glob pattern using the expected prefix and extension.
  for existing_file in "$prefix"*.csv; do
    # Ensure the expanded pattern is actually a file.
    if [[ -f "$existing_file" ]]; then
      echo "$existing_file"
    fi
  done

  echo
done
```

And a sample execution:

```sh
$ ls
bar_123.csv  baz_3456.csv check.sh     foo_12.csv   foo_542.csv
$
$ ./check.sh 
FILES WITH PREFIX: foo
foo_12.csv
foo_542.csv

FILES WITH PREFIX: bar
bar_123.csv

FILES WITH PREFIX: missing
```

Comment: Thank you @Ionuț G. Stan for your inputs.As per my understanding in the solution you. mentioned the names must be identical completely. This didn't work in my case as my filenames will also have some numbers before .csv (example : bar_2029.csv) the only detail I'll have is bar.

Comment: @nick I see. I've edited my answer with a small sample script that uses a glob pattern to list similar files, and by similar I understood to mean those that start with a certain prefix and and with a certain extension (.csv in this case).